# Configure TCP endpoint when vagrant up or reload

Tags: shell, azure, vagrant, endpoint

I'm using Vagrant to run an Ubuntu VM with Microsoft Azure provider, but I need to create an endpoint on this VM.
I've done it installing azure command-line tools with

```
npm install azure-cli -g
```

and after that

```
azure vm endpoint create {VM-Name} 80 8080
```

VM is running fine without problems. But I don't want to configure the endpoint manually anymore. I would like to create it when I run vagrant up. I don't want to use vagrant provision, because this shell instruction should not be executed in my VM, but in my physical machine.
There is no options such as verbose in vagrant, which would have permitted me to see what it really does with the Vagrantfile, and what I should do to implement a shell command like this one in it.

Comment: Looks like the implementation of endpoints happen when launching VM with vagrant up --provider=azure for the first time. But if you happen to delete the endpoint originally created with azure.tcp_endpoints, it can't be created again when you vagrant reload. Still don't know why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansver to initial question, do the following:
in vagrantfile add following string in azure provider section:

```
azure.tcp_endpoints = '80:8080'
```

hope this help.

answer to your question about verbose output:
you may run `vagrant up --provider=azure --debug`
for additional debug information.

if you need to run local scripts you may try to use `vagrant-triggers` plugin

Comment: Yes, I've solved this problem since that. I'm marking this answer as right.